# Fluctuating Transferspeeds on Nextcloud

Tags: nextcloud, iperf, odroid, openmediavault

I'm running OMV 4 on an Odroid UX4 with 3 WD Reds (ext4) connected over 2 USB3 ports (1 usb Hub so two drives share a USB3 port)

The 3 drives are connected using Unified Filesystem which basically merges the three drives into one.
I'm also using snapraid.

On top of this I'm running nextcloud.

Now when I upload a folder with some files to nextcloud using drag and drop, the uploadspeed fluctuate between 150mbit/s and 0 it's constantly going up and down.
[image]

I used `iperf` to check the network speed between my labtop and my ODROID which is running nextcloud and I get a decent 906Mbits/s:

```
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  1.05 GBytes   906 Mbits/sec
```

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/sharedfolders/test/ bs=8k count=1000k; rm -f /sharedfolders/test/`

returns
`(8.4 GB, 7.8 GiB) copied, 153.854 s, 54.5 MB/s`

I was monitoring that transfer and the writespeed was constant.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the file chunking of nextcloud.
[nextcloud docks](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/15/developer_manual/client_apis/WebDAV/chunking.html#:%7E:text=Chunked%20file%20upload-,Introduction,once%20they%20are%20all%20uploaded.)